# excel vba copy multiple column based on column header listed in cell ranges

Tags: excel, vba

I want to copy multiple columns from sheet1 to sheet2 based on column header (eg. Date, Name, ID, Amount,etc), the column header is listed in sheet3, A1:A10.eg. Date, Name, ID, Amount,etc.

After googling for few hours, i got below code, but it only work copying one single column, how can i copy multiple column? which part of the code do i need to change? Would appreciate your time and help.

Thank you.

```
Sub CopySpecifcColumn()

    Set MR = Range("A1:e1")

    For Each cell In MR

        If cell.Value = "Date" Then cell.EntireColumn.Copy

    Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested:

```
Sub CopyCols()

    Dim h As Range, f As Range, sht1, rngDest As Range

    Set sht1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set rngDest = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("a1") 'start pasting here

    'loop through the headers to copy
    For Each h In ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A10").Cells
        'find the header on sheet1
        Set f = sht1.Rows(1).Find(h.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            'found the header: copy the column
            f.EntireColumn.Copy rngDest
            Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(0, 1) ' move destination
        End If
        Set f = Nothing
    Next h

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, this is another way of doing this, great! thank you and you guys are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

You are only copying one column (the "Date" column), because your *If* statement only copies the *Date* column. By continuing with your current method, you can copy the columns of the rest of the data in `Range("A1:e1")` by writing statements for those columns like so:

```
Set MR = Range("A1:e1")

For Each cell In MR

If cell.Value = "Date" Then 
    cell.EntireColumn.Copy
End If

If cell.Value = "Name" Then    '<- Add these for each column title
    cell.EntireColumn.Copy
End If 

If cell.Value = "ID" Then 
    cell.EntireColumn.Copy
End If

If cell.Value = "Amount" Then 
    cell.EntireColumn.Copy
End If


Next cell
```

There is another way of doing this by storing each Column Title in an array, and to copy each column by looping through the array which shortens the code and can be written more flexibly. Looping through ONLY the column titles in an array is also much faster than searching through each cell of the column ranges.

Looping by Column Titles would go something like this, with more details to work out:

```
Dim Sh2Cell As Range
Dim Sh3Cell As Range
Dim Sh2Title As Range
Dim Sh3Title As Range

Set Sh2Title = Sheet2.Range("Title Range")
Set Sh3Title = Sheet3.Range("Title Range")

For Each Sh2Cell In Sh2Title
    For Each Sh3Cell In Sh3Title
        If Sh2Cell = Sh3Cell Then
            'Copy column'
        End If
    Next
Next
```

Comment: Hi Anthony, thanks for sharing. i tried your code but it only copy the last header, ie. Amount, no selection for date, Name & ID, anything missing from the code?

Comment: @Robin I've added adjustments to the code. The issue with only copying the last header is because the If statements did not have an End. Adding an End to each If statement will ensure that each one runs. 

In terms of writing this using arrays, I will update my answer when I finish writing the code.

Comment: Thanks you Anthony for your time and help!!

Comment: Anthony, let me try later and come back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities here.

1. This one is more in way with your code. Instead of checking `If cell.Value = "Date"` you need to check if `cell.Value` exists in Sheet3, A1:A10. `Find` method should be fine here, however, it returns error if the value was not found. Be aware of this.
2. This one will work the other way around. For every cell in Sheet3, A1:A10, find a column header in sheet1 and copy that column. `Find` method will work here again, but it will be safer, as long as you keep names in Sheet3 without typos.

Of course you still need to paste copied data before you copy next column. There is third way to do this, by selecting all columns and then copy all of them, but I find it more complicated, and pasted data can have empty columns.